# How to select git commit ranges with inclusive end points

Tags: git

I need to specify all commits downstream of the 1st commit in a git repo.

I am trying to run this command:

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --ignore-unmatch --cached some/path/file' -- 33e0331^..
```

And I am getting:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '33e0331^..': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Because `33e0331` is the first commit in the repo. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 13):

The question was specifically about using `git filter-branch`, but the way it was expressed applies to many Git commands.  I like to use the term "select with history" here; it's how `git log` and `git rev-list` and anything else that *uses* `git rev-list`—including `git filter-branch`—work.  For other Git commands, writing down a name for a single commit just selects the single commit itself, and we must use the `exclude..include` syntax or similar to get a whole range of commits:

```
git cherry-pick A..B
```

for instance will cherry-pick the commit *after* `A`, and then the commit after that, and so on until it finally reaches commit `B`.  The very similar:

```
git revert A..B
```

will revert commit `B`, then the commit before `B`, then the commit before that, and so on, but stop and *not* revert commit `A`.  (Note that this assumes something about the graph "between" `A` and `B`: the notion of "between" is rather slippery.)

[Mark Adelsberger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45692959/1256452) is the right one for `git filter-branch`, and indeed for any Git command that uses the "select commit with history" mode.  [**Edit**: Oops, I see he has augmented his answer since then!  Well, this is now even more supplemental.]  But what can you do with, e.g., `git cherry-pick`, when you want to cherry-pick commit `A` too?

There are several obvious answers—well, "obvious" once you grasp the commit-graph-following in the first place, and the funky syntactic operations Git provides with things like `A^`:

```
git cherry-pick A^..B
```

means "select commit `B` and all its history, excluding commit `A^` and all of *its* history" and since `A^` means "the parent commit of `A`", this usually does the trick.  You must, of course, be aware of the way that the exclusion itself works: if there are merges in the commit graph, or commit `A` is not an ancestor of commit `B`, the exclusion may not produce what you wanted.

Nonetheless, there are some especially tricky cases where one funky Git syntax comes in handy.  If commit `A` is itself a merge commit, and you want to exclude *all* of `A`'s parents without excluding `A` itself, [there is a syntax for that, documented in the gitrevisions(7) page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html): `A^@` means "all the parents of commit `A`, but not commit `A` itself".

[**Edit, Jun 2021**]: This, unfortunately, cannot be combined with the two-dot syntax, but there *sometimes* is a way to handle it.  We need to use `git rev-parse` with `A^@` first to get the list of commit hash IDs to exclude.  Then we need to prefix each hash ID *in* this list with `^`.  Finally, we need to provide this list, and a "positive reference" to `B`:

```
git rev-parse A^@ | sed s/^/^/
```

achieves the first goal (at least on Unix-like systems using sh or bash), and:

```
git <command> $(git rev-parse A^@ | sed s/^/^/) B
```

then runs the given `<command>` with the hat-prefixed list of commits.  This list is empty when `A` is a root commit.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work with `git cherry-pick` at all, as it now just sees `B`.  So for this particular case we just have to run some sort of "is `A` a root commit" test first (e.g., use `A^..B`).  If `A^` fails because `A` is a root commit, then we can use:

```
git cherry-pick A A..B
```

which will first copy commit `A`, then all commits after `A` up through `B` inclusive.

For `git revert`, the equivalent would be:

```
git revert A..B A
```

when `A` is a root commit (but note that if this revert works at all, it just leaves you with a no-files-in-it-at-all commit).

Comment: just tested this but it doesn't seem to work :/
`$ git revert eab485e2d09076e1cc82485a56c80d729c165b93^@..d71777a7dfa53fa82847119aaede42fbbbf83473 --no-edit
<NEWLINE> fatal: bad revision 'eab485e2d09076e1cc82485a56c80d729c165b93^@..d71777a7dfa53fa82847119aaede42fbbbf83473'`

Comment: However, your other syntax `A^..B` worked perfect, thx :)

Comment: @ElouanKeryell-Even: interesting: I know `<rev1>^@..<rev2>` worked at least once when I tested it (probably back in 2017 when I wrote the answer above). It doesn't *now* though.

Comment: Additional note: I built Git 2.14.0 (dated around Aug 2017) and it does not seem to work there. I wound it all the way back to Git 2.1.0 and it does not work there either. Maybe it never did! I could swear I tested it. (It works without the `..` syntax, but as such, the overall command will need massaging.)

Comment: using exclusive...inclusive ranges is brain damaged. Mercurial got it right. Git sucks. But "Linus is a genius", right? Well apparently not.

Answer (score 4):

Just don't specify the starting point.  If you say `master`, for example, that implies "everything reachable from `master`".  The ability to include a starting point is only to designate some "early history" to exclude.

While that should address the scenario you've put forward, a more general answer to the title question:  You can't.  You don't *really* specify "ranges of commits" (as most people would intuitively define it) at all.

The range notation is a convenience, but it can be misleading.  In non-trivial cases, it can be useful to remember that you can specify (a) that everything reachable from a commit should be excluded, or (b) that everything reachable from a commit should be included.  There are multiple notations for each.  `A..B` means "exclude everything reachable from `A`, but other than that include everything reachable from `B`"; it's a shorthand for something like `^A B` (and, interestingly, it's not actually shorter...)

Now in a simple case, that looks like a range of commits

```
x1 -- x2 -- A -- O1 -- O2 -- B -- x3 -- x4
```

In such a simple case, you could kinda-sotta make it an "inclusive range" by using "parent-of" notation as you tried (`^A^ B` or `A^..B`).

If `A` is a root, as in your example:

```
A -- O1 -- O2 -- B -- x1 -- x2
```

still `A..B` means to include the `O`s and the `B`.  For an "inclusive" range, you would just omit the starting point as in the original form of my answer.  `B` would include `A`, the `O`s, and `B`.

You can stretch your definition of "range" a little bit:

```
x1 -- x2 -- A
        \
         O1 -- O2 -- B
```

Here, `A..B` (which, again, is just `^A B`) would again include just the `O`s and the `B`. It may seem that the "starting point" is not upstream of `B`, but you exclude everything *reachable from* `A`, which includes the `x`s

So now, what would an "inclusive range" even mean?

This is a common usage of the `..` notation, because it allows you to peal the commits from a branch away from the commits of its "parent branch".  (I say "parent branch" in quotes, because this is not a thing to git.  It's just a common interpretation of the branch topology.)

But where you can really lose your mind trying to think of `A..B` as a "range" is something like

```
x1 -- A -- O1 -- O2 -- B <--(master)
                      /
              O3 -- O4
```

Now why are `O3` and `O4` not `x2` and `x3`?  They aren't in the "range" from `A` to `B`...?  Well, they aren't reachable from `A`, and they are reachable from `B`, so they are included.  To get the range (as you might intuitively understand it) you would have to say something like `^A ^o4 B`

Comment: "Now why are O3 and O4 not x2 and x3?" x2 x3 are not in your diagram. Also can you please fix your sentence please ? A..B should include 01 and 02 and not 03 and 04 since 01 and 02 are not reachable from A but are reachable from B. 03 and 04 are not reachable from both A and B because they are both downstream of A and B. Right ?

Answer (score 0):

I your case, you seem to be looking for a way to specify `--all`.

Here is the `<rev-list options>` section of `git help filter-branch` :

```
   <rev-list options>...
       Arguments for git rev-list. All positive refs included by these options are
       rewritten. You may also specify options such as --all, but you must use --
       to separate them from the git filter-branch options. Implies the section 
       called “Remap to ancestor”.
```

and some sample usage in the `EXAMPLES` section.

In your case :

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm ...' -- --all
```